# nested pages in strapi and nextjs

Tags: next.js, strapi

So we want to create a big website with nextjs and strapi.

We sometimes have deep nested pages like
[www.ourwebsite.com/onderwijs/bijbelscholen/parttime-bijbelscholen](http://www.ourwebsite.com/onderwijs/bijbelscholen/parttime-bijbelscholen)

How is this possible?
I have tried to setup dynamic routing in nextjs which is working fine, but I have a problem.

If I want dynamic routes which are all nested I need to do something like this:
[image]

I know it's ugly, I'm sorry.
so now when I go to
[www.ourwebsite.com/onderwijs/bijbelscholen/parttime-bijbelscholen](http://www.ourwebsite.com/onderwijs/bijbelscholen/parttime-bijbelscholen)

I just get the latest word from the URL and take that and put that into my API to get the right data which is working fine! I configured strapi so it finds by slug and not by id. So my API URL looks like this: www.myStrapiInstalation/api/pages/parttime-bijbelschool

but when I go to
[www.ourwebsite.com/onderwijs/parttime-bijbelscholen](http://www.ourwebsite.com/onderwijs/parttime-bijbelscholen)

It's also working! but that's not good! Because it needed to give me a 404 page because it doesn't exist but now it just takes the latest word and gets the data from strapi. My API URL is still this of course: www.myStrapiInstalation/api/pages/parttime-bijbelschool

So what do I need to do?
Is it just not possible to make everything hardcoded and do I need to make nested folders with real names like: 'onderwijs', 'activiteiten' etc.

Or can I make everything dynamic so that people can make nested routes in nested routes in strapi?

I feel like this is a very stupid question, but I'm really stuck here.

Comment: If you don't want a page in the `/onderwijs/parttime-bijbelscholen` path then don't add one in your folder structure. Only create the innermost `index.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Next JS allows [catch-all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes), which is useful for nesting pages and have this format:

```
pages/post/[...slug].js
```

In your example, the pages folder structure would be:

```
pages/secondNest/[...page].js
```

However, since you're using Strapi to fetch the content, the routes of these pages should be known in advance so that if the user navigates to an invalid page, the result should be 404.

You can set the valid routes in Next with [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths). But notice that you will also need to set up a custom controller in your Strapi application to return the content tree of your website the way that `getStaticPaths` expects.

That way, it's ok to use the last part of the URL to get the content.

One disavantage of using catch-all routes, though, is that you must know the base of each URL. For example, if you have the following URLs

- [www.example.com/onderwijs/bijbelscholen/parttime-bijbelscholen](http://www.example.com/onderwijs/bijbelscholen/parttime-bijbelscholen)
- [www.example.com/activiteiten/bijbelscholen/parttime-bijbelscholen](http://www.example.com/activiteiten/bijbelscholen/parttime-bijbelscholen)

the folder structure in `pages` would be:

```
pages/onderwijs/[...page].js
pages/activiteiten/[...page].js
```

The key factor here is that the paths following the base of the URL should be set statically with the help of a custom controller that returns the tree of the content.